# Visual Studio Code - Insert new tabs to the right

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, is there any way to have new tabs open **to the right of all existing tabs**? When I click a file in the explorer, it inserts the new tab to the right of the currently opened file's tab, instead of placing it **at the end** of my tab list.

[See here for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SybIa.png). I'd like the `dashboard.component.html` to open at the end of my tab list, instead of right in the middle of my currently ordered tabs. We have this feature in Visual Studio like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni2nI.png).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try:

```
"workbench.editor.openPositioning": "last"
```

> Workbench › Editor: Open Positioning
>
> Controls where editors open. Select `left` or `right` to open editors to
>   the left or right of the currently active one. Select `first` or `last` to
>   open editors independently from the currently active one.

Click the `gear icon` in the lower left, choose "`Settings`", search for the above setting and change to `last`.